# AWS target groups - One target not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a load balancer that has a target group with 2 targets. One target is in `us-east-1a` and the other in `us-east-1b`. Each of them have a network interface and are healthy. But when I try to navigate to my application, `us-east-1b` always works but `us-east-1a` gives me a time out error.

Comment: Assuming all your appropriate ports and networking communication is open between the two instances. It probably wouldn't hurt to try remove/re-register the 1a target with the load balancer again.

Comment: Already did that and it still doesn't work.